# Proving $\frac{1} {e^z -1} = \frac{1} {z} -1/2$ + 2z $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {z^2 + 4 {\pi}^2 n^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

This question is part of my complex analysis assignement and I am at loss of ideas on how should I approach it. So, I am posting it here.

> Prove the identity $\frac{1} {e^z -1} = \frac{1} {z}$ -1/2 + 2z $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1} {z^2 + 4 {\pi}^2 n^2}$.

well ,only thing which comes to mind is using $e^z =1+z+z^2/2!+...$ but that doesn't seem to yield anything as RHS IS completely different to it.

I am kinda struck on how should i  manipulate LHS to get close to what is given on RHS.

Please shed some light on this.

Comment: Write the function as a contour integral using Cauchy's formula. Blow up the contour and sum over the residues coming from the poles at integer multiples of $2\pi i$.

Comment: @Gary It doesn't decay fast enough. For $2i\pi f(z)/z=\int_{|s-2i|=1} \frac1{(s-z)s(e^s-1)}ds$ it works but it won't be the series the OP asked.

Comment: The process should be done for $$
\frac{1}{z}\left( {\frac{1}{{e^z  - 1}} - \frac{1}{z} + \frac{1}{2}} \right).
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the Weierstrass factorization theorem, $\sin\tfrac{z}{2}=\tfrac{z}{2}\prod_{n\ge1}(1-\tfrac{z^2}{4\pi^2n^2})$. Taking log-derivatives, $\tfrac12\cot\tfrac{z}{2}=\tfrac1z-2z\sum_{n\ge1}\tfrac{1}{4\pi^2n^2-z^2}$. Replacing $z$ with $iz$, $\tfrac12\coth\tfrac{z}{2}=\tfrac1z+2z\sum_{n\ge1}\tfrac{1}{4\pi^2n^2+z^2}$. Subtracting $\tfrac12$ completes the proof.

Comment: OK.  But I imagine the OP is going to be one step in proving that Weierstrass factorization for $\sin$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac1z (\frac1{e^z-1}+\frac12-\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac1{z-2i\pi n})$$ is entire and bounded and it vanishes at $+\infty$

The boundedness is shown in two steps: this expression (which is more or less $2i\pi$ periodic) gives that it is bounded near the poles and replacing $\lim_{N\to \infty}\sum_{n=-N}^N \frac1{z-2i\pi n}$ by your series gives that it is bounded everywhere else.